# setting asp.net CORE 2 authentication cookie while using bearer token authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using `IdentityServer` and `JWT` bearer tokens to authenticate requests in an angular 4 / ASP.NET Core 2 web application.

The authentication all works, and I can obtain the bearer token.
Unfortunately the project has a few pages (like the hangfire dashboard) that require a regular forms authenticated cookie.

How can I programmatically create a cookie, and set it in the angular application so that when I navigate to the legacy pages, the cookie is present, and the user can be authenticated?

The regular login page is still present, and I can login using forms authentication as well, but I would rather just login using the bearer token, and then obtain the authentication cookie as if I had logged in using forms as well.

The bearer token will ensure that an unauthenticated user cannot obtain the cookie, that part is already taken care of. I just need to know how to create the cookie and return it.

Comment: As I know hangfire authorization has nothing to do with cookie authentication and doesn't force you to use cookie authentication.you can still check authorization by JWT token with hangfire .

Comment: That's true, If you know how, that would also answer the question. Unfortunately loading up the hangfire url `/hangfire` in a browser is not going to send any tokens in the header, so the token will not be authenticated. As I have it now, I am checking `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have both Cookies and JWT authentication at the same time in one project.
first add both cookie and JWT authentication in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddCookie(options => options.SlidingExpiration = true)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    // JWT setup
  });
```

in `Configure` method just add `app.UseAuthentication();`

and put

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

on top of controllers where you want change authentication scheme to JWT.

for more info read [Two AuthorizationSchemes in ASP.NET Core 2](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2).